# Рядный тип, символьное представление

Tags: ruby, переменные

Создайте действительную переменную a, в которую запишите число 2.5, в целую переменную b запишите значение 3, в переменную рядного типа str запишите значение "Результат:". В переменную result запишите результат добавления переменных str, символьного представления числа a и символьного представления числа b, причем каждую из них запишите в новом ряду (для переноса на новый ряд используйте специальный символ "\n").

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Задача такая попалась. Только учусь. не знаю как решить

Answer (score 1):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@3UkElUcFWwUjP1JoLxEkCcowhzOKSIiBH6cKCC1svbL/YfGH3xZ6LTRc2XGyyUoIoKEotLs0pAaoBK61TUIrJUwJSQAMR7CRrroKizLwSDahqTev//wE)

```
my $a = 2.5;
my $b = 3;
my $str = "Результат:";
my $result = $str ~ "\n" ~ $a ~ "\n" ~ $b;
print($result);
```

Comment: " ~"-таких значков не изучали, да и код что-то не работает

Comment: А по ссылке всё работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYYPv.png

Comment: @Qwertiy ну не указал человек язык программирования, что же вы над ним издеваетесь и `Perl` ему подсовываете.

Comment: @mazik7512, я хотел [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), но оказалось, что там нельзя объявлять переменные нормально... Так что перл - это ещё нормально)))

Comment: @Qwertiy страшный вы человек...